# JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'

Tags: json, parsing

Data contains (/`&quot;`/):

```
 {"test":"101","mr":"103","bishop":"102"}
```

script:

```
console.log($.parseJSON(result));
```

I'm getting error,

```
JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'.
```

Comment: Based on error message, maybe you have an unquoted apostrophe in there? Those must be escaped using backslash, or Unicode escape (\u0027)

Comment: sorry thats a type, there i only have &quot;

Comment: Your JSON as posted is clean. Please edit to reflect actual JSON string if it's different.

Comment: What do you mean by "Data contains (/&quot/)"?

Comment: yes mysjon seems to be correct, but i can't able to parse it with jquery parseJSON method, any thoughts ?

Comment: Please show the real JSON value.

Comment: FYI, the json i receive contains &quot;, but browser rendered here as " properly

Comment: {&quot;Chairman of the Board&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;General Manager&quot;:&quot;10&quot;}       this what i get .

Comment: That's not valid JSON, but over-escaped JSON. Where does this come from?

Comment: im working salesforce platform, visualforce page. is there anything i can do to read in javascript ?

Comment: If anyone got any idea, let me know, other wise please feel free to ignore it, im going to try other approach.

Answer (score 140):

Had same issue when used single quotes in JSON file, changed to double quotes for all string properties/values and it's working OK now.

Change:

```
JSON.parse("{'wrongQuotes': 5}")
```

To:

```
JSON.parse('{"rightQuotes": 5}')
```

Comment: Such a stupid thing! You're right. This one didn't work:

     JSON.parse("{'ple':2}")

But this one did:

     JSON.parse('{"ple":2}')

Comment: Thanks bud, echo "{'success':false}"; did not work, echo '{"success":false}'; did. :)

Comment: @Pithikos, the JSON spec requires double-quotes, not single-quotes. It's just the way the spec is defined: http://www.json.org/

Comment: @JonathanM thanks. Although my question was rhetorical. I just expect the answerer to give some more info as to WHY double quotes are needed :)

Comment: A year late but when I used JSON.stringify() I ended up with %22 instead of quotes. This was fixed by using string.replace(/\%22/g, '"')

Note: The replacement is ' " ', without the spaces

Comment: a few years later, I am getting the same error but i am using JSON.parse(this.responseText);  any suggestions?

Comment: I just forgot to surround the keys with qoutes

Answer (score 38):

If you're receiving the JSON with the encoded `&quot;`, you'll have to replace each instance of `&quot;` with a true `"` before doing `JSON.parse`. Something like:

```
myJSONstring.replace(/&quot;/ig,'"');
```

Comment: +1 did the job for me. do you know the reason for the &quot; coming in? Is that the browser putting these since the mimetype is not javascript or json from the server side?

Comment: @Sid, depends on where and how you're getting the JSON. It's possible someone has mis-coded the programming on the server to URL encode the JSON string.

Answer (score 18):

My case was even simpler.

Having confused JSON with plain JS, I didn't put the object keys in double quotes.

❌:

```
{
    title: "Hello World!"
}
```

✅:

```
{
    "title": "Hello World!"
}
```

The irony is, Postman even highlighted this to me, but I ignored. Sleep is the answer.

Comment: Same here, it's so simple to overlook.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who is using laravel blade and declaring a JS variable in a view.

You need to use:

```
var json = JSON.parse('{!! $json !!}');
```

Otherwise you will get this error due to the quotes being parsed as "

Answer (score 3):

Change 
 `{"test":"101","mr":"103","bishop":"102"}` 
To 
`'{"test":"101","mr":"103","bishop":"102"}'`

if this is coming from the server **(PHP)** 
i.e `<?php $php_var = ["test" => "101", "mr" => "103", "bishop" => "102"]?>` 
then on **Javascript** end 
`var javascript_var = $.parseJSON('<?= json_encode($php_var) ?>')`;

Answer (score 3):

```
/* suppose your json are single quote, it's necessary replace it single quote before, a simple example*/

let ojson = "{'name':'peterson'}";
ojson = ojson.replace(/'/g, '"');
ojson = JSON.parse(ojson);
console.log(ojson['name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using stringifying before parsing:
`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))`

Answer (score 1):

I copied my JSON object from password vault to Postman which messed up formatting somehow - whitespace around brackets was causing the JSON.parse error:
[image]

Removing whitespace has fixed the issue:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

for example, if u get something like this

{ "location": "{'lat': 4.6351144, 'lng': -74.12011199999999}" }

from your server, or recently get a bad converted format.
first,get your string

```
myItemString = "{'lat': 4.6351144, 'lng': -74.12011199999999}"
```

and change the keys using replace, and later  json.parse,
'key'  to ---> "key"

```
     const key1 = myItemString.replace("'lat'",'"lat"')
      const key12 = key1.replace("'lng'", '"lng"');
      const obj = JSON.parse(key12)
      console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = JSON.parse('{!! $json !!}');
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: And what is this because it will definitely throw an error...

Comment: probably some php thingy

Answer (score 0):

```js
let lng_lat = '{lng:-50.31756617529646,lat:-27.168027359667732}';

let converted = JSON.parse(lng_lat.replaceAll(':', '":"').replaceAll('{','{"').replaceAll('}','"}').replaceAll(',','","'));

console.log(converted);

// Or

lng_lat = lng_lat.replaceAll(':', '":"');
lng_lat = lng_lat.replaceAll('{','{"');
lng_lat = lng_lat.replaceAll('}','"}');
lng_lat = lng_lat.replaceAll(',','","');
converted = JSON.parse(lng_lat);

console.log(converted);
```