# Returning json without &quot; after migrating to python 2.7

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have just migrated from python 2.5 to python 2.7 and replaced simplejson with the built-in json. But now I get a json error "JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'."

The returned json is:

```
{
  "stat"    : "ok",
  "code"    : "200",
  "message" : "Retrieved departments from account.",
  "result"  : [{&quot;id&quot;: &quot;5486563022602240&quot;, &quot;name&quot;: &quot;The     
  New Establishment&quot;}, {&quot;id&quot;: &quot;6049512976023552&quot;, 
  &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Ye Olde Joynt&quot;}]
}
```

It seems I can do some string replacing in the frontend ([JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013582/json-parse-expected-property-name-or)), but shouldn't it rather be my service, which returns the correctly formated data ? I currently generate the data in python like this:

```
def department_getlist(self):
    self.message = 'Retrieved departments from account.'
    results = []
    for d in self.account.departments:
      results.append({
        'id': str(d.key().id()),
        'name': d.name
      })
    self.result = json.dumps(results)
```

How do I generate the data in python, so it is returned in the correct format (if that is the way to do it)?

thanks

Thomas

Comment: Are you sure that's the full code to generate the json? I'm not seeing any `id` or `name` keys within the returned json at the top.

Comment: @Michael0x2a you are right. I updated the returned json to show the correct version. The other json was from another part of the application

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that somewhere down the line, you're calling `json.dumps` twice rather then once.

Inside your `department_getlist` function, you do `self.result = json.dumps(results)`. I'm guessing somewhere else, you do something to the effect of:

```
message = {
  "stat"    : "ok",
  "code"    : "200",
  "message" : "Retrieved departments from account.",
  "result"  : self.results
}

output = json.dumps(message)
```

If so, you're calling `json.dumps` on the `self.results` variable twice, and escaping the quotation marks on the second pass. When your frontend Javascript parses and displays the JSON, it probably displays the escaped strings as `&quot;` somewhere down the line, rather then `\"`.

Try changing the line in the `department_getlist` function to `self.result = results` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @MichaelOx2a thanks for your suggestion. It made me do a backtrace to follow the execution of the code. The solution was to use {% autoescape off %} in my json-template: {
  "stat"    : "{{ status }}",
  "code"    : "{{ code }}",
  "message" : "{{ message }}"{% if result %},
  "result"  : {% autoescape off %}{{ result }}{% endautoescape %}{% endif %}
}

Comment: @ThomasD - Ah, I see. I guess I was completely wrong then :).  You should consider writing up your solution as a new answer and accepting it for the benefit of anybody else in the future who might have the same problem.

Comment: your answer might not have been exactly correct, but you made me go down the right path :-) I added a short description as an answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment made by Michael0x2a I backtraced my code and found the solution to be to 
use
{% autoescape off %} in my json-template:

```
{
  "stat"    : "{{ status }}",
  "code"    : "{{ code }}",
  "message" : "{{ message }}"{% if result %},
  "result"  : {% autoescape off %}{{ result }}{% endautoescape %}{% endif %}
}
```