# Unable to parse json String in javascript which is response of java method

Tags: java, javascript, json

Following is my controller which returns String

```
@RequestMapping("/hello1")  
    public @ResponseBody  
        String hello1() {  
           String jsonString = "[{\"deviceId\": \"  e71b0be12218393e121cb728595af68995889fb9\",\"deviceName\": \"  Xcaliber?s iPad3\",\"serialNumber\": \"  DMPH9E74DJ8R\",\"modelNumber\": \"  MC706\",\"productType\":\"  iPad3,1\",\"deviceClass\": \"  iPad\"},{\"deviceId\": \"\", \"deviceName\": \"\",\"serialNumber\": \"\",\"modelNumber\": \"\",\"productType\": \"\",\"deviceClass\": \"\"}]";
return jsonString;
}
```

I am getting this string as response in javascript.
    and I am trying follwing code in javascript

```
var deviceJsonDetails = $.parseJSON(response);
         for(var count = 0;count < response.length; count++){
                             var id = count+1;
                             alert(deviceJsonDetails[count].deviceId);
                             $("#deviceId"+id).html(deviceJsonDetails[count].deviceId);
                             $("#deviceName"+id).html(deviceJsonDetails[count].deviceName);
                             $("#serialNumber"+id).html(deviceJsonDetails[count].serialNumber);
                             $("#modelNumber"+id).html(deviceJsonDetails[count].modelNumber);
    }
```

But it is giving error on `var deviceJsonDetails = $.parseJSON(response);`
Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'

Can you please tell me where is the fault or any alternate solution to parse same string in js?

Comment: "*But it is giving error*" - what error?

Comment: Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'

Comment: could you add it to your post? It's important part of a question. Thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013582/json-parse-expected-property-name-or

Comment: Check what server returning in HTTP response (Developer Tools in Chrome, Firebug Plugin in Firefox for example) and check if syntax is corrct by using JSONLint web site validator for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your JSON string in http://jsonlint.com/

The correct string that you need to parse should be: Remove the "\"

```
[
    {
        "deviceId": "e71b0be12218393e121cb728595af68995889fb9",
        "deviceName": "Xcaliber?siPad3",
        "serialNumber": "DMPH9E74DJ8R",
        "modelNumber": "MC706",
        "productType": "iPad3,1",
        "deviceClass": "iPad"
    },
    {
        "deviceId": "",
        "deviceName": "",
        "serialNumber": "",
        "modelNumber": "",
        "productType": "",
        "deviceClass": ""
    }
]
```

Comment: the JSON string is in double quotes that's why \ is used only to escape ".

Comment: after you return the string and before your parse can you remove "\"