# How to convert javascript text to an JSON

Tags: javascript, json

How to convert text

> "{width: '300'}"

to a JSON object in JavaScript?

JSON.parse does not work (*Unexpected token w in JSON at position 1*).

Comment: because your string is not valid json cannot parse.`Object.fromEntries(text.replace(/[{}']/g, "").split(",").map(prop => prop.split(": ")))` . split by , assuming there are more properties

Comment: Check this answer
[question]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013582/json-parse-expected-property-name-or

Comment: or `JSON.parse(text.replace(/'/g, '"').replace(/(\w+)\s*:/g, '"$1":'))` this one chatgpt'd

Answer (score 0):

you have two ways to do this.

**1. eval**

because your text is in a valid javascript object format, as the other answer said you can use the `eval` function. the `eval` function will run the text as javascript code. so consider that anything can run in the eval so you have to trust the text. never use `eval` if the text comes from the user.

```js
const text = "{width: '300'}"
const object = eval(`(${text})`)
```

**2. regex and replace**

if the text is always in a valid javascript object format, you can turn the text into a valid JSON and then parse it. to do this you have to add `"` for the keys and replace `'` with `"` for the values. you can use this code for these replacements.

```js
let text = "{width: '300'}"
text = text.replace(/([,:{]\s*)([^,:"'}]+)(\s*[:])/g, '$1"$2"$3').replace(/'/g, '"')
const object = JSON.parse(text)
```